# DOM object loses reference after passing through jquery functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, dom

Something odd has occured to me with an object reference.

I have the following DOM with a pass-through in an `onclick`

```
 var tdButtonDOMCopy = $('#tD'+catSeq+'Button');
```

And this is the in-Jquery-created-button with reference to its next function:

```
 tdButtonDOM.replaceWith('<button id="buttonChange" onclick="approveFormEdit(\''+tdButtonDOMCopy+'\')"\n\
                          class="btn btn-primary">Sla wijziging op</button>');
```

I want to pass this entire DOM element `[Object object]` as parameter to its next function:

```
function approveFormEdit(tdButtonElement) {
   alert(tdButtonElement.html());
   .... - Omitted -
```

Now here is the funny thing:

In the `onclick` section the object `tdButtonDOMCopy` is seen as a DOM-object and I can use the `.html()` method on it.

Though, once the object reaches the function `approveFormEdit` the `.html()` method no longer works because it has lost the referrence DOM-object somehow.

[image]

What is going on here?

This is the fiddle with context

[jsfiddle.net/1vdwv5r8](http://jsfiddle.net/1vdwv5r8)

Comment: please don't mix obsolete DOM0 inline event handlers and jQuery.

Comment: You are putting an object into a string context, by concatenating it with other text literals. So its toString method is called - and for objects that do not define their own, a generic version is called, and that only returns the text `[object Object]`. You can not pass complex objects this way. Listen to what @Alnitak said - and use _proper_ jQuery methods. If you need a reference to a certain object, then store it on the element that needs to refer to it later using f.e. https://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: Thank you for these suggestions. The passing DOM was new to me, as before I re-wrote the entire DOM html at the .replace() function so I'd rather just copy the element than rewrite it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing it in quotes thus its a *string literal* so the error is expected as *.html()* is a jQuery method.

You need to remove pass the `tdButtonDOMCopy` without quotes, then it will be treated as variable

```
tdButtonDOM.replaceWith('<button id="buttonChange" onclick="approveFormEdit(tdButtonDOMCopy)" class="btn btn-primary">Sla wijziging op</button>');
```

---

However, I would recommend you to pass the selector use `data-*` custom attribute which can be retrived in the event handler;

```
var tdButtonDOMCopy = '#tD' + catSeq + 'Button';
tdButtonDOM.replaceWith('<button id="buttonChange" data-target="' + tdButtonDOMCopy + '" class="btn btn-primary">Sla wijziging op</button>');

function approveFormEdit() {
    var targetSelector = $(this).data('target'); ;
    tdButtonElement = $(targetSelector);
}

$(document).on('click', '#buttonChange', approveFormEdit)
```

Comment: Unfortunatly "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"  is what I get with the edit

Comment: I will work with the data- attribute. So far I still get 'undefined' when I let the object use the .html() method but I will try to get the hang of this. Data attribute usage in jQuery is new to me.

Comment: It's too bad but after hundreds of trials there is no possibility of getting the .html() of the copied DOM-element. My context works with both onclick and data-target. The data ID is read as seen in an alert() but that is it. The rest keeps being undifined so I am afraid I need to keep it to re-writing DOMS rather than copying them. 
It was worth a shot though

Comment: @MwBakker, Can you create a fiddle? I will explore and will provide you a solution. if possible please share some detail I might provide an alternate solution. Also unaccept the answer

Comment: The answer is correct as for the information I have given. I did not give more detail since this would create a mess in my question. I will try to make a fiddle, but as plain static code.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1vdwv5r8/    

This is the code I am talking about. It worked before I started messing with copying entire DOM's.

Comment: @MwBakker, https://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/ea2fcafL/ I have only kept the relevant code, hope it helps

Comment: I do want you to know I am very thankful you keep doing the effort helping me. For me this has been a real time-consuming issue to constant trial and error and as it seems I have a now more efficient and working way to do this.